# Activiti diagram mail task deployment in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, activiti

I am new to Activiti and am working on Activiti mail task in eclipse. I want to make an application to send emails using Activiti mail task. I have looked up in the web but couldn't find much help. I have looked up in the Activiti user guide but couldn't figure out from there. Could you help me with this or direct to some useful example or resource (possibly not the Activiti user guide)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create TaskListener and plugin with task events.

ex.

```
<userTask id="usertask2" name="Approved"
    activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_Publisher" activiti:formKey="wf:reviewTask">
    <extensionElements>
       **<activiti:taskListener event="create" class="com.org.cms.test.bpm.EmailNotification">**</activiti:taskListener>            
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Then you can create your EmailNotification class where you can sent email.

Comment: thank you. however can you clarify a bit more? what does TaskListener do?